# Google Drive API List files based on Owners in Shared Drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm building a web project that allows users to filter and list files on a shared Google drive. Using Google Drive API v3 and Javascript I want to be able to filter said files based on the owner or original creator of the file. In order to display all files with "John Doe" as the owner/creator however this query doesn't work.

`"John Doe" in owners`

The list method looks like the following

```
window.gapi.client.drive.files.list({
   'fields': 'nextPageToken, files(*)',
   'corpora': 'drive', 
   'includeItemsFromAllDrives': true,
   'supportsAllDrives': true,
   'driveId': 'XXX',
   'q': '"John Doe" in owners'
})
```

Zero files are returned with this query. Is there any way to list files based on the owner or creator or lastModifyingUser using Google Drive API on a shared Drive?

Answer (score 2):

- "John Doe" in owners works, but it will only find the files to which both "John Doe" AND you have access
- Depending on where the file is located, you might need to specify
  `'corpora': 'allDrives'` and `'supportsAllDrives'=true` in order to obtian results.

Comment: - During my testing I do have access to John Doe's files however ```"John Doe" in owners``` still returns 0 results
- If I set ```'corpora': 'allDrives', 'supportsAllDrives'=true``` I must remove ```driveId``` which narrows the search field to a specific shared folder. In this case using ```"johndoe@email.com" in owners``` will return his files but not all of the files in the shared folder that he is owner of.

Comment: If you get some results, it means that `"johndoe@email.com" in owners` works. If you do not retrieve all files, it must be related to the sharing settings / the drive where the files are stored. Can you make a correlation between the location and the access permissions between the files you obtain in the results and the ones you don't?